# Увеличить изображение в webview по клику

Tags: android, webview

Возможно ли, разворачивать изображение на весь экран, которое находится в WebView? Я видел реализацию через JS интерфейс, но там идет перехват функций, которые разворачивают изображение, а у меня же просто ссылка на картинку. То есть по нажатию открывается браузер и открывается картинка

UPD:

Решение простенькое, как оказалось. Я создал отдельный layout с ImageView внутри и потом перегрузил WebClient как посоветовал @metalurgus:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(".jpg") || url.contains(".jpeg") || url.contains(".png")) {
                mImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ImageUtils.getUIL(getActivity()).displayImage(url, mWebImage);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `WebView` нужно установить слегка переопределенный `WebViewClient`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        //тут мы смотрим на url, и решаем, если это картинка, 
        //то возвращаем true, чтобы WebView не пытался открыть эту ссылку, 
        //и загружаем картинку сами, и  false, если открывать ссылку в WebView

    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделал

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего можно сделать отдельное окошко, в котором по ссылке изображение будет скачиваться и добавляться в ImageView, ну а ImageView можно на весь экран вывести.

Comment: Не берусь говорить, как всё реализовано в Google Chrome, но можно по верх WebView наложить другой RelaitiveLayout и в нём выводить содержимое

Answer (score 0):

Функция *pinch-to-zoom* не работает в `ImageView`. Есть 3 варианта:

1. Загрузить изображение в `WebView` (о чем и говорит ТС);
2. По клику стартовать `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, тогда можно будет выбрать просмотровщик картинки, в котором (как правило) работает zoom (например `Gallery`)
3. Реализовать самому. Например [как здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming)